# How to do mapping multiple touchscreens in Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland

Tags: xrandr, touchscreen, xinput

For X-Window (Or Ubuntu 20.x), I can do "xinput map-to-output {device_id} {display_name}" to map multiple touchscreen inputs to video output.

Now Ubuntu 22.04, Wayland by default, xinput does not give me the touchscreen device id anymore.
Can you help, tell me how to do multi-touchscreens mapping to videos?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/426944

Comment: `xinput` is an Xorg program; what the X in the name represents.. Also there is no Ubuntu 20.x so your question is rather, and seems to miss understand display server protocols.  Please be clear with details & don't make them up (20.x)

Comment: Hello. 22.04 does not exist. It is scheduled to be released on the 21 st of April. Till it is any question is off limits. After the release do an update and upgrade and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426944/what-is-the-wayland-equivalent-of-xinput-list) provided by Nmath did not help with map-to-output problems.  In my case I have a vertical screen and need to calibrate it with map-to-output which could be run under Ubuntu 20.04 X.org.  The reason we're trying Ubuntu 22.04 Xwayland is for its a lot better performance running vnc...  I also post a question describing my scenario here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704326/how-to-calibrate-touch-screen-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience.  I see many questions but no answers...

Comment: Hi, Anyone help - How to map USB touch input to video output on Ubuntu-Wayland shell?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with switching back to X.

```
sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment `WaylandEnable=true` and change it to `WaylandEnable=false`

Restart gdm

```
 systemctl restart gdm3
```

or reboot system.

Then get the id of your touchscreen input from the external monitor:

```
xinput
```

Get the id of your external monitor display

```
xrandr
```

Map input to output:

```
 xinput map-to-output [touchscreen id ext. monitor] [id ext. monitor]
```

in my case:

```
xinput map-to-output 13 DP-1
```

- I have to map it, whenever I disconnect/connect the monitor again
- the id of the touchscreen input alternates always between two numbers

UPDATE:

Here a bash script you can use after plugin the external monitor to avoid to search IDs whenever disconnected/connected:

```
#!/bin/bash

IDENTIFIER=<Identifier xinput shows, e.g. USBII_CTP_CONTROL>

IDS=$(xinput |  grep -E ".*$IDENTIFIER.*id=[0-9]+" | grep -v 'Keyboard' | grep -oP 'id=\K[0-9]+')

for ID in $IDS; do
    #echo "xinput map-to-output $ID DP-1"
    xinput map-to-output $ID DP-1
done
```

Comment: Thank you Gaston for this information. I know many people do this way (set to XOrg)  to resolve from this problem.
I sent emails to many places to report this bug on Wayland graphical shell, but nothing happen. 
Hope Ubuntu/Wayland will have an update soon to resolve this problem.

Comment: And Thank you for the script. It is great.